# C++ Class and Scope Issue

Tags: c++, class, scope

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

// Contact.h
class Contact
{
public: 
  Contact( ); 
  Contact(int, int, int); 
  void display(); 
private: 
  int left; 
  int middle; 
  int right; 
};

//Bank.h
class Bank // Bank class definition
{
    public:
    Bank( );
    Bank(int bank_ID, Contact phone, Contact fax);
    void display();
    private:
    int bank_ID; // 4 digit integer
    Contact phone; // object three integer pieces: ###, ###, ####
    Contact fax; // object three integer pieces, ###, ###, ####
};

// Loan.h
class Loan
{
    public:
    Loan(Bank bank, ID id);
    void display( );
    private:
    Bank bank;
};

Bank::Bank( ){

}

Bank::Bank(int bankID, Contact phoneIN, Contact faxIN){
  bank_ID = bankID;
  Contact phone(555, 555, 555);
  Contact fax(111, 222, 3333);

  cout << "Works here\n";
  phone.display();
  fax.display();
}

void Bank::display() 
{
  cout << "Bank: " << bank_ID << endl;
  cout << "Doesn't work here :(\n";
  phone.display();
  fax.display();
}

Contact::Contact( ) 
{  
}

Contact::Contact(int l, int m, int r) 
{ 
  left = l; 
  middle = m; 
  right = r; 
}

void Contact::display() 
{
  cout << "Number: " << left << "-" << middle << "-" << right << endl; 
}

Loan::Loan(Bank bankID) 
{ 
  bank = bankID;
}

void Loan::display() 
{ 
  bank.display();
}

int main( ) 
{ 
  Loan loan1(Bank(1234, Contact(), Contact()));
  cout << "Display loan1 \n"; 
  loan1.display();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get the part:

```
void Bank::display() 
{
  cout << "Bank: " << bank_ID << endl;
  phone.display();
  fax.display();
}
```

to actually print out the phone and fax numbers but it's only giving me random numbers. It works if I move the phone and fax display below their creation, but doesn't in here. What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide all the code neccessary to understand your question without following external links.

Comment: stackoverflow.com questions must be complete questions, rather than a link to some other site. Please post a complete question.

Comment: Even better, try to reduce your code to a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updated post. I tried to trim it down as much as I know how.

Comment: @Revolt Time to fire up your debugger and step through the code.

Comment: This example is far from beeing minimal^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that probably causes your problem is this:

```
Bank::Bank(int bankID, Contact phoneIN, Contact faxIN){
    bank_ID = bankID;
    Contact phone(555, 555, 555);
    Contact fax(111, 222, 3333);

    cout << "Works here\n";
    phone.display();
    fax.display();
}
```

Here you create local variables called `phone` and `fax`, you are not using your class members.

For using your class members write either

```
phone = Contact (...);
```

or use a member initialization list like this:

```
Bank::Bank(int bankID, Contact phoneIN, Contact faxIN):phone(...){
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was under the impression that Contact phone and fax were able to be used anywhere in Bank since they're declared in the Bank class.